# My simple javascript code for parseFloat is ignoring the decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsefloat

Here is the code:

```
function updateCartSubtotal() {
    var subtotal = 0.00;
    $('span.item-subtotal-value').each(function () {
        subtotal = subtotal + parseFloat($(this).text()); //24.00 for example.
    });

    console.log(subtotal); // Logs: "144"
    $('span.cart-subtotal-value').text(subtotal); //Places: "144" in the .text().
    $('span.cart-subtotal').text(subtotal);
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? Why is this ignoring the two trailing zeroes?

It's adding correctly, just not showing the decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`123` and `123.00` are the same. When displaying a float there is no reason to display unnecessary digits.

More important, floats are not specific to currencies - so if decimal digits would be displayed, there would have to be **many** more.

If you want to display the number with a certain number of digits, use [`subtotal.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). It gives you a string with the correct amount of decimal digits:

```
>>> 123.00
123
>>> (123.00).toFixed(2)
"123.00"
```

So your code could look like this:

```
$('span.cart-subtotal-value, span.cart-subtotal').text(subtotal.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: In this case, I **need** to display those digits. This is for showing a price subtotal. So the two extra zeroes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [`number_format`](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481) function from PHPJS, as this will also include thousand separators that are commonly found in currencies.

Comment: Why not use something [already available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) in JavaScript? When thousand separators are needed/wanted, you are right though - then the function you linked is a good idea.